# 32 bit vs 64 bit MATLAB executable applications

Tags: matlab, 32bit-64bit, matlab-compiler

I have a 64 bit MATLAB installed on my computer.
I am not allowed to install a 32 bit MATLAB on my machine.
I wrote a code and converted it to an executable using application compiler.
Now employees with 32 bit operating systems can not run the executable.

The question is:
Is there a way to create a 32 bit application using a 64 bit MATLAB?
(again, I am not allowed to install a 32 bit MATLAB on my machine)

Comment: when you compile, the flag `-largeArrayDims' is set for 64 machines. In theory if you remove it it should work for 32. Note that I am working with mex files, but I guess there is some kind of option in the app compiler

Comment: According to: [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112720-how-do-you-produce-win32-exes-with-deploytool-in-64-bit-matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112720-how-do-you-produce-win32-exes-with-deploytool-in-64-bit-matlab), "You are running from a Windows command line (not a MATLAB command line)." So you cannot use this -win32 from inside MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks @AndreBigure
 
but I am using the GUI to create the app (clicking on the app menu bar) It gives you no option to make it compatible with 32 bit operating systems.
 
What is the other way (of creating executable applications) in which you can remove the -largeArrayDims flag?